# Applying calculations on large data set

Tags: bigdata, computation

I'm currently optimizing our data warehouse and processes which uses it and i'm looking for some suggestions. 
The problem is that i'm not sure about the calculations on retrieved data.

For make things more clearer for example we have following data stucture:

```
id : 1
param: static_value
param2: static_value
```

And let's consider that we got about 50 million entries with this structure.
Also let's assume that we are querying this data set about 30 times per minute which results every time at least 10k entries.

So, in short we got these stats:

- Data set: 50 million entries.
- Access frequency: 30 / s.
- Resulting data size: ~10k results

On every query in resulting data set i have to go thought every entry and apply on it some calculations which results a field (for example **param3** )  with it's dynamic value. For example:

Query2 ( 2k results ) and one of it's entries:

```
id : 2
param: static_value_2
param2: static_value_2
param3: dynamic_value_2
```

Query3 ( 10k results ) and one of it's entries:

```
id : 3
param: static_value_3
param2: static_value_3
param3: dynamic_value_3
```

And so on..

The problem is that i can't prepare the field *param3* value  earlier than i get it's values by query because of many dynamic values which are used in calculations.

**Main question:**

Is there any guidelines, practises or even the technologies for optimizing this kind of „problems“ or implementing this kind solutions?

Thanks for any information.

**Update 1:**

The field **"param3"** is calculated on every query in every data result entry, it means that this calculated value is not stored in any storage it just computed on every query. I can't store this value because it's dynamic and depends on many variables due this reason i can't store it as static value when it's dynamic.

I guess it's not good practise to have such implementation?

Comment: Is your existing data warehouse stored in an RDBMS (and if so, which one), or some other form of data storage?

Comment: We currently using MongoDB for data storage and retrieval purposes. It means that we have a document data structure which are provided in examples.

Comment: I don't know if I've got it right, but if you're trying to update values in the same entries (table rows), it's probably a good idea to store each round of calculation results into another place, so you won't have to deal with locks because some threads are trying to write while some other are trying to read from the same entry